# PDO MySQL querying independent of database structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

To use PDO to interact with a MySQL database, assuming named placeholders, requires some knowledge of the database structure:

```
$db->("INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname, age) value (:fn, :ln, :age)");
```

Is there a way of using prepared statements with named placeholders without such knowledge, allowing for changes in table structure without needing to change the code. Alternatively, is there a way to query the database for table structure?

Comment: I can't get your problem. What named placeholders has to do with this question?

Comment: You need to know the names of the columns in the table

Comment: I'm trying to find a generic solution to abstraction for the process without needing database-specific information to set it up

Comment: all right but named placeholders are NOT names of the columns

Comment: Why do you want such a generic solution?

Comment: How do you query a db without knowing its structure? Writing a query without knowing the structure seems for me like writing a MySQL query without knowing the MySQL syntax

Comment: Use desc table to get structure dynamically. Thats for mysql of course.

Comment: That's the type of solution I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to observe your business model:

```
select 
    column_name,
    column_type
from 
    information_schema.columns 
where 
    table_schema = 'yourschema'
and table_name = 'yourtable';
```

Parse this result, and built the insert queries on the fly with php. With the `column_type` information you can map the PDO::XXX datatype when you bind the values.

Comment: expand on this please

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the internal mechanics of a MySQL database

Comment: this will return all the columns names and types of a given table in one of your given schema. Execute it as any other pdo query in php, fetch the results (`while ($row = $db->fetch()) {}`) to build the insert query dynamically ('INSERT INTO TABLE (' . $row['column_name'] . '...')

Comment: You'd also need to know in advance the kind of values you want to insert. You don't mention it in your problem.

Comment: You could just fetch column_type from the columns table. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist sorry i said it wrong. I meant that you can indeed built the column names but how would you know dynamically tue values to map to them?